# Remove active TabControl indicator in AvaloniaUI

Tags: c#, avaloniaui

I'm trying to use the TabControl/Item features from AvaloniaUI but I've got this little annoying blue bar indicating which tab I have selected.

[image: The blue bar in question]

Then I've got the src for my tabcontrol here:

```xml
<Window.Styles>
        <Style Selector="TabControl">
            <Setter Property="TabStripPlacement" Value="Left"/>
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,10,0,0"/>
        </Style>
        <Style Selector="TabControl WrapPanel">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#d4d6d9"/>
        </Style>

        <Style Selector="TabItem">
            <Setter Property="FocusAdorner" Value="{x:Null}"/>
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="200"/>
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="21"/>
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="34"/>
            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#d4d6d9"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#94a0b0"/>
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0 0 0 0"/>
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="10 0"/>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
        </Style>
        
        <Style Selector="TabItem:focus">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#f0f0f0"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#94a0b0"/>
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0 0 0 0"/>
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="10 0"/>
        </Style>
        

        <Style Selector="TabItem:selected">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#94a0b0"/>
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0 0 0 0"/>
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="10 0"/>
        </Style>
        

    </Window.Styles>


        <TabControl x:Name="MenuTabs">
        <TabItem x:Name="ServerConnection" Header="Connect">
            <Canvas>
                <TextBox x:Name="AddressField" Watermark="Server Address" Margin="300,300,160,160" Width="340" AcceptsReturn="False" AcceptsTab="False"/>
                <Button x:Name="Mount" Content="Mount network location"/>
            </Canvas>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem x:Name="Settings" Header="Preferences">
            <Canvas>
                <Label>Placeholder</Label>
            </Canvas>
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
```

I've trawled the DevTools trying to see any possible field I could change but no luck. All the solutions people seem to be showing online are for the android side of things and have simple fields that don't seem to exist when I try them. Anyone know how to get rid of it? I'd thought about changing the template used but I have no idea if or how that would work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try it:

```
<Style Selector="TabItem:selected /template/ Border#PART_SelectedPipe">
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="0"/>
</Style>
```

Or

```
<Style Selector="TabItem:selected /template/ Border#PART_SelectedPipe">
    <Setter Property="IsVisible" Value="False"/>
</Style>
```

The first simply shrinks the blue bar so it isn't visible, and the second disables visibility outright.

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?